# Insert into associative table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert into an Associative table on Visual Studio 2013, but I also believe I could have the structure for the tables set up incorrectly. What I need to happen is the Associative table needs to take the primary keys of both the Tasks and Student tables.

Expected Result:

```
StudentID   TaskID      Status
----------- ----------- ------
1           1           N
1           2           N
1           3           N
1           4           N
1           5           N
1           6           N
1           7           N
2           1           N
2           2           N
2           3           N
2           4           N
2           5           N
2           6           N
2           7           N
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STUDENT] (
[StudentID]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentID] ASC));


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TASKS] (
[TaskID]       INT            NOT NULL,
[TaskName]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[TaskCategory] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TaskID] ASC));


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ASSOCIATIVE] (
[StudentID] INT        NOT NULL,
[TaskID]    INT        NOT NULL,
[Status]    NCHAR (10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TaskID] ASC, [StudentID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_ASSOCIATIVE_STUDENT] FOREIGN KEY ([StudentID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[STUDENT] ([StudentID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_ASSOCIATIVE_TASKS] FOREIGN KEY ([TaskID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TASKS] ([TaskID]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO ASSOCIATIVE(StudentID, TaskID, Status)
SELECT
    s.StudentID, t.TaskID, 'N'
FROM STUDENT s
CROSS JOIN TASKS t
```

If you want to run this again and you want to avoid PK violation, add a `NOT EXISTS` condition:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM ASSOCIATIVE a
    WHERE
        a.TaskID = t.TaskID
        AND a.StudentID = s.StudentID
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I wanted to add data to the STUDENT table when the student is added and run this query  is there an operation like the VALUES @StudentId? This would mainly be to avoid running into violations of the primary keys.